# How to check if Being edited on CMSDESK

Tags: kentico

I'm new to ASP and definitely new to Kentico. but i am fairly moving along.

Anyway. i am building this layout where there is a hidden div element:

```
<div style="display: none;">
  <cms:CMSWebPartZone ZoneID="someContentZoneHere" runat="server" />
</div>
```

The problem with this script is that is does not show the Web Part Zone on the Design Page and i cannot add a Data inside it. Si i need to remove the `style` only when it is on the `CMSdesk`.

i have been thinking to use if else to solve the problem, but i do not know what to compare?

```
  <% if(site is not in CMSDESK || CMSSITEMANAGER) { %>
    //with style  attribute
    <div style="display: none;">
  <% }else{ %>
    //no style  attribute
    <div>
  <% } %>
```

or are there any other ways to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition you are looking for is:

```
if(CMS.PortalEngine.PortalContext.ViewMode != CMS.PortalEngine.ViewModeEnum.Edit && 
   CMS.PortalEngine.PortalContext.ViewMode != CMS.PortalEngine.ViewModeEnum.Design)
```

You can also do it the other way round and check for `CMS.PortalEngine.ViewModeEnum.LiveSite`. Check [the full list](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/8_2/api/html/T_CMS_PortalEngine_ViewModeEnum.htm) of possible values.